# Multi-column Conditional Formatting and Row Export in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need to (a) indicate and (b) export several columns of data into a separate sheet, but only the rows that satisfy a certain condition: three columns (which are not exported) must be after today's date.

I'm new to coding, and spreadsheets for that matter, but this is the logic behind it:

If (F2, G2, and H2) are all dates after today, then:
(a) A2 turns green or something, and
(b) Row 2 turns up on Sheet 2

I feel like this has a simple solution but please help!

Comment: Welcome to the Web Applications site. Please take a look to site's [tour](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For conditional formatting, apply the following to A2: "Custom formula is"

```
=AND(F2>TODAY(),G2>TODAY(),H2>TODAY())=TRUE
```

(You can then indicate what the range of formatting should be, e.g., A2:A to get all A column except the header).

To filter the content, use either Query or Filter. Here is an example with [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en):

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:E,Sheet1!F:F>TODAY(),Sheet1!G:G>TODAY(),Sheet1!H:H>TODAY())
```

If you place this on Sheet 2, it will pick the columns A-E from the rows where the stated conditions hold.

---

Note that having the same condition enforced in two different places is not future-proof: someone might change the condition in one place and forget to change in the other. I would add another column to Sheet 1, such as "Export":

```
=AND(F2>TODAY(),G2>TODAY(),H2>TODAY())
```

which will contain TRUE if the row is to be exported. (One can use the `IF` statement to enter custom strings there.)  Then both conditional formatting and the filter would use that column.